# Правильно ли организован код?

Tags: c#, массивы, инспекция-кода, структуры

Очень смущает "зависимость" методов:

> Scoreboard(Train[] train) <- SortArray(train) <- Show(train)

Как от этого избавиться?

**Условие**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс **Program**:

```
using System;

namespace Train
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Train[] trains = new Train[2];
            TrainManager.Scoreboard(trains);
        }
    }
}
```

Класс **Train**:

```
using System;

namespace Train
{
    struct Train
    {
        private string destination_name;
        public string Destination_Name
        {
            get { return destination_name; }
        }

        private int train_number;
        public int Train_Number
        {
            get { return train_number; }
        }

        private string departure_time;
        public string Departure_Time
        {
            get { return departure_time; }
        }

        public Train(string destination_name, int train_number, string departure_time)
        {
            this.destination_name = destination_name;
            this.train_number = train_number;
            this.departure_time = departure_time;
        }
    }
}
```

Класс **TrainManager**:

```
using System;

namespace Train
{
    static class TrainManager
    {
        public static void Scoreboard(Train[] train)
        {
            string destination_name;
            int train_number;
            string departure_time;

            for (int i = 0; i < train.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter train number: ");
                train_number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Enter destination time: ");
                destination_name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.Write("Enter departure time: ");
                departure_time = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                train[i] = new Train(destination_name, train_number, departure_time);

                Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 30));
            }
            SortArray(train);
        }

        private static void SortArray(Train[] train)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < train.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int q = 0; q < train.Length; q++)
                {
                    if (train[i].Train_Number <= train[q].Train_Number)
                    {
                        Train g = train[i];
                        train[i] = train[q];
                        train[q] = g;
                    }
                }
            }

            Show(train);
        }

        private static void Show(Train[] train)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("////////////////////TRAIN SCHEDULE////////////////////");

            for(int i = 0; i < train.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 30));
                Console.WriteLine("Train number {0}:", train[i].Train_Number);
                Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 30));

                Console.WriteLine("Destination name: {0}", train[i].Destination_Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Departure time: {0}", train[i].Departure_Time);

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: на самом деле совсем непонятно, почему метод сортировки, должен выводить результат сортировки. Если вынести вызов Show ничего не поменяется

Comment: вообще непонятен смысл статического класса TrainManager

Answer (score 1):

Ксли говорить про код, то что тут неправильно:

1. Статические члены
2. Сортировка за квадратичное время
3. Мешанина логики и представления в одном классе

Как избавиться: разделить ответственности, выкинуть статику, не забыть про юнит тесты.

```
void Main()
{
    var logic = new MainLogic(new UserInteractor(), new ScheduleLogic());
    logic.Run();
}


struct Train
{
    private string destination_name;
    public string Destination_Name
    {
        get { return destination_name; }
    }

    private int train_number;
    public int Train_Number
    {
        get { return train_number; }
    }

    private string departure_time;
    public string Departure_Time
    {
        get { return departure_time; }
    }

    public Train(string destination_name, int train_number, string departure_time)
    {
        this.destination_name = destination_name;
        this.train_number = train_number;
        this.departure_time = departure_time;
    }
}

class UserInteractor
{
    public Train[] ReadTrains (int trainCount)
    {
        var trains = new Train[trainCount];

        string destination_name;
        int train_number;
        string departure_time;

        for (int i = 0; i < trainCount; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter train number: ");
            train_number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter destination time: ");
            destination_name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter departure time: ");
            departure_time = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            trains[i] = new Train(destination_name, train_number, departure_time);

            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 30));
        }

        return trains;
    }

    public void Show(Train[] train)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("////////////////////TRAIN SCHEDULE////////////////////");

        for (int i = 0; i < train.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 30));
            Console.WriteLine("Train number {0}:", train[i].Train_Number);
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 30));

            Console.WriteLine("Destination name: {0}", train[i].Destination_Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Departure time: {0}", train[i].Departure_Time);

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}

class ScheduleLogic
{
    public Train[] Schedule(Train[] trains)
    {       
        return trains?.OrderBy(x=>x.Train_Number).ToArray();
    }
}

class MainLogic
{
    private UserInteractor _interactor;
    private ScheduleLogic _scheduleLogic;

    public MainLogic(UserInteractor interactor, ScheduleLogic scheduleLogic)
    {
        _interactor = interactor;
        _scheduleLogic = scheduleLogic;     
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var trains = _interactor.ReadTrains(2);
        trains = _scheduleLogic.Schedule(trains);
        _interactor.Show(trains);
    }
}
```